# Why can you set the height of a html outer div using CSS, but not the inner which remains collapsed?

Tags: html, css

just a small question to help improve my understanding of html/CSS behaviour. I've noticed with the following code:

```css
.nav {
  border:1px solid black;  
  height:100px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can set the height of the outer div "nav".

However, if I try and do the same with the inner div .container, this remains collapsed until it is filled with "Hello". Could I ask what explains this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Works perfectly for me.. http://codepen.io/Omnitored/pen/GrOawB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you wonder why `.container` can't be seen without any child elements? If you add something that has a height (as a `<h1>` element) it expands to the height of that element (see the difference between 1. and 2. `.container`)

If you want `.container` to be expanded by default, you can add a `height: 100%`, which expands it to the height of the outer container.

```css
.nav {
  border:1px dotted black;  
  height:100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.container {
  border:1px solid red; 
}

.container2 {
  border:1px solid green;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <div class="container2">
  </div>
</div>
```